# Ошибка в программе, которая не отображается в IDE Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk, mobile-development

Я попытался разработать небольшую игру: *кликер*. Компиляция успешная, установка на устройство тоже удачное. Однако, после клика на кнопку, приложение вылетает. Прошу помочь. Вот весь код:

```
 package com.arslee07.eliteclicker;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 public int clicks = 0;
Button btnClick;
TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

    View.OnClickListener oclBtnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicks++;


           //clicks = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());

            textView.setText("ELITE CLICKS: "+ clicks);
        }
    };
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(oclBtnClick);

     }
 }
```

Comment: Если ошибка не связана с компиляцией, то и не увидите при компиляции. Смотрите стек трассы приложения в logcat

Comment: чтобы увидеть ошибки, нужно что то узнать о logcat и stacktrace. Не бывает такого, чтобы приложение не работало и не было ошибки при этом. В частности сейчас вы получаете Null Pointer Exeption на строке с `textView.setText()` , так как объект не был проинициализирован. То, что вы не видите ошибки или не знаете, где смотреть  - не значит, что ее нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так же как вы связали

```
btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
```

связать и

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
```